# blank measures in ssas cube even when data is in source table

Tags: deployment, ssas, cube, measures

I've been working on a cube that has data in the fact table that is browsable through the DSV but after being processed seems to have blank values for all the measures. The common suggestions include checking the that the CALCULATE command is still visible in the Calculations tab for the measures (it is there and its not commented out or anything) and checking there's actually data for the cube (there is data). The partitions are set for the whole table so its not like data is being filtered out. Interestingly if I redeploy the same SSAS project and therefore effectively the same code to a brand new SSAS database then its fine (measures show up). I guess I'm wondering if someone can throw some light on why this behaviour occurs?

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest checking the cube size first. You can use following recipe http://www.ssas-info.com/analysis-services-scripts/1197-powershell-script-to-list-info-about-ssas-databases

Depending on the settings, it is possible that you have missing/mismatched dimension keys. 
That can cause your data not being loaded.